# Responsive HTML CSS slider problems

Tags: html, css, slider, responsive

I've just copied [this codepen](https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/ehKpi) to my page.

It works well, but I have some other content on my page as well, and the problem is that when I import this code, it destroys all links and other images on my page. Does anyone know why is this happening, and how to solve this? :)

**HTML**

```
<base href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/">
<div id="slider">
<figure>
<img src="austin-fireworks.jpg" alt>
<img src="taj-mahal_copy.jpg" alt>
<img src="ibiza.jpg" alt>
<img src="ankor-wat.jpg" alt>
<img src="austin-fireworks.jpg" alt>
</figure>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}

body { margin: 0; } 
div#slider { overflow: hidden; }
div#slider figure img { width: 20%; float: left; }
div#slider figure { 
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
}
```

Comment: You should provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

It probably destroys all links and everything else because of

`<base href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/">`

Which will make it so that your links and references are based on off of that. As per [mozilla developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base):

> The HTML `<base>` element specifies the base URL to use for all relative
>   URLs contained within a document. There can be only one  element
>   in a document.

**Solution for you case in particular:**

Remove that base href element on top of your page, and update the sources for each image in the slider individually for its absolute URL.

Answer (score 0):

**here's what i have so far and it's working properly **

```
<div id="slider">
        <div class="slider-title">
            <h2>best seller</h2>
        </div>
        <figure>
            <img src="simon-lee-TW93DCT6T_U-unsplash.jpg" alt="sample photo">
            <img src="colin-cassidy-wdG7v-9pJ1A-unsplash.jpg" alt="sample photo">
            <img src="massimiliano-corradini-Nylf-HeGX2w-unsplash.jpg" alt="sample photo">
            <img src="studio-blackthorns-C7vX_SBPrqk-unsplash.jpg" alt="sample photo">
            <img src="simon-lee-TW93DCT6T_U-unsplash.jpg" alt="sample photo">
        </figure>
    
    </div>
```

**and this is my css**

```
    #slider {
    margin-top: 25px;
    background: #417378;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#slider figure {
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 500%;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
    animation: 20s slider infinite;
    }
    #slider figure img {
    width: 20%;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: -25px;
    }
    @keyframes slider {
    0% {
        border-radius: 10px;
        left: 0;
    }
    20% {
        border-radius: 10px;
        left: 0;
    }
    25% {
    border-radius: 10px;
        left: -100%;
    }
    45% {
        border-radius: 10px;
        left: -100%;
    }
    50% {
        border-radius: 10px;
        left: -200%;
    }
    70% {
        border-radius: 10px;
        left: -200%;
    }
    75% {
        border-radius: 10px;
        left: -300%;
    }
    95% {
        border-radius: 10px;
        left: -300%;
    }
    100% {
        border-radius: 10px;
        left: -400%;
    }

}
```